# heroku не видит папку cogs

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sys, traceback
import asyncio
from pathlib import Path
import os

def get_prefix(bot, message):

    prefixes = ['.']

    if not message.guild:
        return '$'

    return commands.when_mentioned_or(*prefixes)(bot, message)



cogs = os.listdir("./cogs")
initial_extensions = cogs = ['cogs.roles']

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents = discord.Intents.all())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in cogs:
        bot.load_extension(extension)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    print( 'Бот подключен' )

token = open ( 'token.txt', 'r' ).readline()
bot.run(token)
```

При загрузке на хероку выдает такую ошибку:
2022-09-06T05:30:56.016206+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bot_example.py:32: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
2022-09-06T05:30:56.016222+00:00 app[worker.1]:   bot.load_extension(extension)

Comment: используйте `await bot.load_extension(extension)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `bot.load_extension(extension)` вы создаёте корутину, но не вызываете её. Для этого Нужно использовать `await`:

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    for extension in cogs:
        await bot.load_extension(extension)


asyncio.run(main())
```